# inserting records using a transaction

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

I am trying to insert records in the database using Eloquent. I have the following code wherein I am creating a new user and then inserting a new row in the profile table so that the user update his/her profile as and when he/she logs in.

```
$user = new User();
$user->fill(Input::all());
$user->save();

$profile = new Profile();
$user->profile()->save($profile);
return Response::json(array('message' => 'Your account has been created.'));
```

The biggest disadvantage of my code here is - it leaves my tables in a half fried state. For example if the user's record were created but for some reason , there was an issue while creating the profile record, a user can exist where a profile has not been created for him/her.

Is there a way this can be circumvented ? I know I can check for the existence of the profile when I am about to access the user's profile (and create it if it has not been created - with the default values) but I would like to know if there are any other methods apart from this.

I believe using transaction is the way forward, if yes - can you please provide me an example ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use transaction here:

```
$user = new User();
$user->fill(Input::all());
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $user->save();
    $profile = new Profile();
    $user->profile()->save($profile);
    DB::commit();
    return Response::json(array('message' => 'Your account has been created.'));
}
catch (QueryException $e) {
    DB::rollBack();
    return Redirect::to('url')->withInput()
            ->with('error', 'Error occurred. Try again or contact administrator');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$user = new User();
$user->fill(Input::all());

$profile = new Profile();

return DB::transaction(function() use ($user, $profile) {
    $user->save();
    $user->profile()->save($profile);

    return Response::json(array('message' => 'Your account has been created.'));
});
```